# 95th percentile of average

Tags: average, percentile

All is know is that the average of a data set (that i do not know ) is 22,2.
And that is 95th percentile is 32,8.

Is it possible to calculate its 80th percentile with only this informations ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: of course no if you don't know the distribution

Answer (score 0):

The z-score formula is: $$z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$ where $x$ is a point on the distribution, $\mu$ is the mean, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

Since the z-score is related to a z-score table that maps the z-score to the percentiles with a one-to-one correspondence (bijection), if we know all three variables we can calculate the percentile.

We can randomly choose a point that we know on the curve, and we know the mean which is given in the question. However, the **standard deviation** is missing, so that is the only piece of information we need to *calculate the $80$th percentile*.

Answer (score 0):

The SD is approximately 6.44, derived by taking the difference between the mean and the 95th and dividing by 1.645.  The 80th percentile is approximately 27.6, derived by multiplying the SD by 0.84 and adding to the mean.

Comment: What does SD stand for?

Comment: Standard deviation?